# Spotify API returns a 404 not found when trying to fetch information for podcasts

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests, spotify

Search if an answer is already available: No

**1. Summarize the problem**

Spotify introduced the ability to fetch information about podcasts and shows. [Details here.](https://developer.spotify.com/community/news/2020/03/20/introducing-podcasts-api/)

I am using the Python "requests" package to generate the request URL to get metrics like no_of_followers and so on (I am not sure if they're available for podcasts), so I tried getting metadata for a show.

The endpoint I used to get information about a show: `GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/shows/{id}`

```
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
}
# endpoint used "https://api.spotify.com/v1/shows/{id}"

lookup_url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/shows/3IM0lmZxpFAY7CwMuv9H4g" #"The Daily" podcast example
print(lookup_url)

r = requests.get(lookup_url, headers=headers)
print(r)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```

However I receive the following error response:

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/shows/3IM0lmZxpFAY7CwMuv9H4g
<Response [404]>
404
{'error': {'status': 404, 'message': 'non existing id'}}
```

***Questions at the end***

**2. Describe what you’ve tried**

I tried pulling similar information using the search endpoint, there, I do get a valid response. Informative and as expected when searching for artists but the response data seems to be missing for the show I searched.

The endpoint I used to search for a show/artist: `GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/search`

Using the search endpoint to find information about a show/artist:

```
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
}
endpoint = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search"
data = urlencode({"q":"the daily","type":"show"})
# data = urlencode({"q":"drake","type":"artist"})

lookup_url = f"{endpoint}?{data}"
print(lookup_url)

r = requests.get(lookup_url, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
r.json()
```

Get the output for the show above as:

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=the+daily&type=show
200
{'shows': {'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=the+daily&type=show&offset=0&limit=20',
  'items': [None,
   None,
   None,
   None,
   None,
   None,
   None,
   None,
   None,
   None,
   None,
   None,
   None,
   None,
   None,
   None,
   None,
   None,
   None,
   None],
  'limit': 20,
  'next': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=the+daily&type=show&offset=20&limit=20',
  'offset': 0,
  'previous': None,
  'total': 14755}}
```

If I try to search information for an artist, I get good results:

```
{'artists': {'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=drake&type=artist&offset=0&limit=20',
  'items': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4'},
    'followers': {'href': None, 'total': 48844145},
    'genres': ['canadian hip hop',
     'canadian pop',
     'hip hop',
     'pop rap',
     'rap',
     'toronto rap'],
    'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4',
    'id': '3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4',
    'images': [{'height': 640,
      'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/60cfab40c6bb160a1906be45276829d430058005',
      'width': 640},
     {'height': 320,
      'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/5ea794cf832550943d5f8122afcf5f23ee9d85b7',
      'width': 320},
     {'height': 160,
      'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/8eaace74aaca82eaccde400bbcab2653b9cf86e1',
      'width': 160}],
    'name': 'Drake',
    'popularity': 98,
    'type': 'artist',
    'uri': 'spotify:artist:3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4'},
...output clipped for readability
```

**3. Questions:**

1. Am I trying to pull information about a show incorrectly? I tried to use the search endpoint as mentioned below - which seems to work well for artists or tracks but not for shows.
2. Is it possible to get metrics for a show - like followers, times_episodes_played and historic data?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have upvoted for demonstration of significant research effort prior to posting here. However, please consider editing your question to focus on a single inquiry in accordance with Stack Overflow's [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines. To answer your second question, [the documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/shows/get-a-show/) shows those properties you're asking for aren't available as part of the API endpoint you've engaged. I would imagine that data is kept extremely close as it affects ad revenues, etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the guideline. I agree with the "times_episodes_played" metric. That might not be viable to get. But followers should be doable, already get that for artists. Also, after giving the documentation one more try I found out something interesting. If you try out the "Try It - Example Request" [here](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-show/?id=38bS44xjbVVZ3No3ByF1dJ) with the "Show id" and the "OAuth Token" and Market as blank you get the "non-existing id" error I saw earlier. However, if you enter a random market (which is optional) it works! Works for search endpoint as well

Comment: It is true that the `market` parameter is documented as *optional* - you might wish to send a message to the email they list on the linked page to lodge a bug report or for them to reach out with additional support.

Comment: Indeed, market isn't as optional as the documentation makes out as I also discovered this same issue with Podcast Shows and Episode endpoints but some bits of the documentation do include mention of Market being required to get them so is a little unclear if don't see that under a different API-call's documentation

Answer (score 5):

The [Get a Show](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference-beta/#category-shows) endpoint does seem to require the **Market** parameter to be supplied. In the section for that parameter although marked as *optional* it states:

> If a country code is specified, only shows and episodes that are available in that market will be returned.
> If a valid user access token is specified in the request header, the country associated with the user account will take priority over this parameter.
> Note: If neither market or user country are provided, the content is considered unavailable for the client.

I also experienced issues with Podcast **Shows** and **Episodes** as also assumed as with other content you still get something when not supplying the **Market** parameter until I'd noticed that the following meant that without it you get nothing back, which is the problem you're experiencing,

> If neither market or user country are provided, the content is
> considered unavailable for the client.

The documentation should really state that in this case, unlike for Songs etc the **Market** value is not optional, might be worth raising an issue on the [Spotify for Developers](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/bd-p/Spotify_Developer) forum